# Cannot set Header of GroupBox when ControlTemplate applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the following control template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CriterionTemplate" Name="CriterionTemplate">    
    <GroupBox Name="CriterionGroupbox">
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="KeywordSelectionButton"  Grid.Column="0" Height="50" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource HiddenButtonStyle}">
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
            <Image Name="SelectionImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50"/>
            <Label Name="SelectionLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ClearButton"  Grid.Column="2" Height="50"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In my MainWindow code behind, I dynamically create a variable number of controls having this template

```
var template = this.FindResource("CriterionTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
GroupBox gb = new GroupBox()
{
    Template = template,
    Header = "MyCustomHeader",
};
gb.ApplyTemplate();
```

I create a bunch of those groupboxes and add them to some stackpanel. So far so good.
Problem now is that the Header attribute of the groupbox **is not set**. Its just blank. The groupbox itsself with the template looks perfect, just the Header is empty. Once I remove the template, the Header is displayed correctly.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to add a TemplateBinding to the Label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by myself.

There was a structural problem within the code itsself. I defined two GroupBoxes. One within the template, one outside in the code-behind.

To modify the Header of the outer GroupBox in the code-behind did nor reflect the UI, however modifying the inner one which is defined in the template DID.

Anyway I have to re-think my design here.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you haven't specified how and where your `Header` will be displayed.

Once you decide to show Header in a Label, you need to

1. Set `TargetType` of Control Template to `GroupBox`. This will make sure that TemplateBinding of `GroupBox` properties work.
2. You have to do TemplateBinding like this

   `<Label Content = "{TemplateBinding Header}">`

Comment: I dont want a custom label somewhere in the GroupBox, I want to set and modify the original "Header" attribute of the GroupBox.

Comment: When you bind to Header and it is editable and you make changes, then it will be reflected in the Header Property.

Comment: The solution works somehow, except that the content of the Property is displayed somewhere in the middle of the GroupBox, but not where typically the Header would be displayed (on the top-left of the GroupBox, interrupting the border lines).

Comment: Make change <GroupBox Name="CriterionGroupbox" Header = "{TemplateBinding Header}">